# Phaser3 mute on Firefox

Tags: firefox, phaser-framework, mute

I got a problem with Phaser3 recently, and looking for someone who can help me to figure out.

I use a button to control mute or turn on sound, it works in Chrome, but it doesn't work properly in Firefox: if I mute the sound, it can't turn it on again. Here's my code:

```js
if (GameApp.Game.sound.mute) {
  this.m_volumeBtn.setFrame(this.m_volumeBtn.getData(DATA_KEY_VOLUME_ON));
  GameApp.Game.sound.mute = false;
}
else {
  this.m_volumeBtn.setFrame(this.m_volumeBtn.getData(DATA_KEY_VOLUME_OFF));
  GameApp.Game.sound.mute = true;
}

console.log(GameApp.Game.sound.mute)
```

No matter how many times I click the button, the console always prints `false`. I'd like to know if there's some points I missed or if I have to use another way to make it work.

p.s. `GameApp.Game.sound.mute` is from `BaseSoundManager`, and extends `Phaser.Events.EventEmitter`.

Comment: What is your audio filetype?

Comment: I use m4a and mp3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I just used a global variable to keep track of the mute status:

```
isMute = !isMute;
game.sound.mute = isMute;
if (isMute === true) {
    muteAudioText.setText("SOUND\nOFF");
} else {
    muteAudioText.setText("SOUND\nON");
}
```